# Generating PDFs when JavaScript is being used

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, yii2, mpdf

I'm not 100% sure of my error here. I am getting this encoding output when I am trying to generate a PDF:

`%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�S(T0�300@!�ҹ�iab�gai�`ji�g`

I am using Yii2 and the highcharts package https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget along with the mPDF package https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf.

My hope was to be able to generate a browser version of this graph and also a PDF version. The browser version works fine, but the PDF attempt doesn't. My code in the action is:

```
  if($pdf == true){ // render as pdf

  $content = $this->renderPartial('_overallPDF', [
    'model' => $data,
  ]);

  $doc = new Pdf([
    // set to use core fonts only
    'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
    // A4 paper format
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    // portrait orientation
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
    // stream to browser inline
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
    // your html content input
    'content' => $content,
  ]);

  return $doc->render();

}
```

I am not sure of the problem here, could it be due to highcharts being a js library and the presentation done in browser?

Either way if anyone could help me find a solution to generate the graph as a PDF that would be great!

Comment: that is a pdf. you've just failed to tell your browser that you're outputting an `application/pdf` mime type, so it's being treated as text/plain, or maybe text/html.

Comment: @MarcB Hi Marc, looking at the package instructions https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf I don't think you have to do this becuase of the `return $doc->render()`? I am able to output a very simple PDF like `<p>hello</p>` if that is what is in my _overallPDF file being used in the partial render call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this has been already answered : what you are trying to do is simply not possible since MPDF supports basic javascript... And this has nothing to do with yii2.

If you really want to output highcharts graph in your pdf document, you should use a server side tool, e.g. : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside